# Is there an activity to stop wf4?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

Is there a way to use an activity to stop the execution of its workflow?

I have multiple `TryCatch` activities and `If` activities and it would be nice to be able to stop the workflow after catching an exception or if certain criteria aren't met in my `If` activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the TerminateWorkflow activity to stop a workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Just a word of warning for anyone else who might run into this, `TerminateWorkflow` won't actually terminate your workflow if you put it inside a `CompositeActivity` (it will only terminate the composite.)

Comment: Can you provide an example workflow for this? I couldn't reproduce what you describe.